# Site Design Celebration

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, design

It looks like the site's new design is going to launch *soon* maybe [this week](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13824982#13824982).  This has been *long* in coming, so how are we going to celebrate?

Comment: Thats really good news ... we can celebrate by answering all unanswered questions :)

Comment: Exciting news. Looking for some good celebration ideas.

Comment: @Dheer - I like your idea. I've added 3 bounties for unanswered questions since reading your comment.

Comment: @Dheer can you make that an answer?

Comment: @Dheer Seconding that! Would be a good answer.

Comment: I'm aiming to launch next weeek(tue or wed). Please let me know if you need any promotional materials done for this.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Would you put up something on your blog?  Jin offered to do graphics? :-)

Comment: @C.Ross Of course! I spend more time here than on my own writing. Happy to put something up.

Answer (score 6):

We can conduct a celebration drive to clean up the house. Focus on Unanswered questions.

We have 154 with no answers, we can take a look;
- Some should be easy to answer given that I see similar question answered by experts here. Maybe they got missed when there were first posted and we haven't had the time to look back.
- Some can be closed I think

We have 34 questions with answers.
- The answers may just need upvote

I looked at some of them last week and collectively they should'nt be too difficult to square away.

Comment: If the top ten posters each agree to take a bit of time to answer a few and bounty a few more, we'll make great progress.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Taking your queue, I have put bounty on 2 ...

Comment: Nice. The count is now 131. It will be great to see participation and progress.

Comment: Noone wants my bounties...:-(

Answer (score 5):

How about a

### Contest!

There could be a variety of criteria (questions asked, answered, up-voted, shared, reviewed, etc.) to reach specified levels to enter prize draws. I'm thinking of something similar to contests held at other Stack Exchange sites like [the contest at Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/the-new-ipad-is-here-ask-different-and-win-one), and [at Super User](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/), and [at Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/diablo-3-is-coming-train-with-us).

Won me a useful prize in one of those contests, and a T-shirt in another. Working my way up the leaderboard was especially fun!

Perhaps Stack Exchange Inc. and its community team could help with the mechanics necessary to run such a contest, and provide a budget (or willing sponsors!) for some prizes — books, financial calculators, software, etc.? :)

Comment: Looking into this. We've done contests in the past that mostly aimed to get content generated. This particular one would need to just be all about us telling everyone that we wuv you and appreciate you waiting patiently, and have some fun. Ideas for mechanics? `tpost@stackoverflow.com` - I'm all ears :D

Answer (score 3):

How about a

### Festive Community Chat!

We can meet in chat, discuss the history of the site, and share clips of our favorite "financial advisers" being ridiculous.

Comment: ... and debate if it is "adviser" or "advisor" :)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea General rabble rousing encouraged :-).

Comment: What's there to debate? It's advisor. My spell checker approved, it even puts a nice red line under it to emphasize how correct it is! I love seeing that line every time I sign my blog post:-D

Comment: I would **advisE** you look at this: - an AdVisor - http://www.miraclelacevisor.com/LOGOSCHURCHILL.gif

Comment: @MrChrister and I spent some time in chat earlier, with Jin, but no one else came.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Oi vey, busy day at work.  I moderated, but I honestly forgot about the design.